# How do I apply a theme in GitHub pages?

Tags: github-pages

I got pages to build for the jekyll-theme-tactile - [they're here](https://davidthielen.github.io/LouisHowe/).

For this case, this is my docs/_config.yml (before today):

```
theme: jekyll-theme-tactile
title: Louis Howe User Guide
description: How to use the app - for Volunteers and Managers
appdomain: https://louishowe.azurewebsites.net
```

And Settings | Pages I had "Build and deployment" set to "Deploy from a branch" with that set to master/docs.

This all works - is what I did here everything that I'm supposed to do?

---

And now the problem, I am trying to use the just-the-docs theme. For this my docs/_config.tml is:

```
theme: just-the-docs
title: Ohana User Guide
description: How to use Ohana - for Volunteers and Managers

appdomain: https://louishowe.azurewebsites.net

aux_links:
  "Ohana website": https://louishowe.azurewebsites.net/
```

And Settings | Pages I had "Build and deployment" set to "GitHub Actions". But [the instructions for this](https://just-the-docs.com/) do not say what action to set it to, or how.

This does not work. No new pages are build. What else I need to set for this?

Comment: If you feel that my answer has solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted'. If you're still facing issues, please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get started with just-the-docs theme is to use their [template](https://github.com/just-the-docs/just-the-docs-template/generate). However, this requires you to create a new repository.

To use the theme in an existing repository (as in your case) you can follow the instructions from [here](https://github.com/just-the-docs/just-the-docs-template/blob/main/README.md#hosting-your-docs-from-an-existing-project-repo). I've included a copy of the instructions below:

### Hosting your docs from an existing project repo

You might want to maintain your docs in an existing project repo. Instead of creating a new repo using the [just-the-docs template](https://github.com/just-the-docs/just-the-docs-template), you can copy the template files into your existing repo and configure the template's Github Actions workflow to build from a `docs` directory. You can clone the template to your local machine or download the `.zip` file to access the files.

#### Copy the template files

1. Create a `.github/workflows` directory at your project root if your repo doesn't already have one. Copy the `pages.yml` file into this directory. GitHub Actions searches this directory for workflow files.
2. Create a `docs` directory at your project root and copy all remaining template files into this directory.

#### Modify the GitHub Actions workflow

The GitHub Actions workflow that builds and deploys your site to Github Pages is defined by the `pages.yml` file. You'll need to edit this file to that so that your build and deploy steps look to your `docs` directory, rather than the project root.

1. Set the default `working-directory` param for the build job.

   ```yaml
   build:
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     defaults:
       run:
         working-directory: docs
   ```
2. Set the `working-directory` param for the Setup Ruby step.

   ```yaml
   - name: Setup Ruby
       uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
       with:
         ruby-version: '3.1'
         bundler-cache: true
         cache-version: 0
         working-directory: '${{ github.workspace }}/docs'
   ```
3. Set the path param for the Upload artifact step:

   ```yaml
   - name: Upload artifact
       uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
       with:
         path: "docs/_site/"
   ```
4. Modify the trigger so that only changes within the `docs` directory start the workflow. Otherwise, every change to your project (even those that don't affect the docs) would trigger a new site build and deploy.

   ```yaml
   on:
     push:
       branches:
         - "main"
       paths:
         - "docs/**"
   ```